# convert the dataframe columns to int dtype given that the columns might have multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wish to convert certain dataframe columns to int type(Note: my dataframe might have more than the current examples and quite dynamic so I wish to find a best way to convert it).

Codes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_p = pd.DataFrame({'1.0': [1,2,3],
                    '2.0': [4,5,6],
                    '3.0': [7,8,9],
                    '4.0': [4,5,6],
                    '5.0': [4,5,6],
                    '6.0': [1,1,1],
                    'info': ['abc','dfg','ghj'],
                    'new_info': [4,5,6],
                    'new_t_info': ['your','master','data']})

df_p.columns.astype(int) #Normally I use this to convert it, however, since my columns contain string that cannot be converted to int then I am lost. Please note, I might have more than the current columns and wish to find a more dynamic ways to do it.
```

Current :

```
    1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 info    new_info    new_t_info
0   1   4   7   4   4   1   abc 4   your
1   2   5   8   5   5   1   dfg 5   master
2   3   6   9   6   6   1   ghj 6   data
```

Expected:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   info    new_info    new_t_info
0   1   4   7   4   4   1   abc 4   your
1   2   5   8   5   5   1   dfg 5   master
2   3   6   9   6   6   1   ghj 6   data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) before apply the previous code an then 
we could use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors = 'coerce'`  and [`pd.Index.to_series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) +  [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
df_p=df_p.sort_index(axis=1)
s = df_p.columns.to_series()
df_p.columns = s.replace(pd.to_numeric(s,errors = 'coerce').dropna().astype(int))
#   1  2  3  4  5  6 info  new_info new_t_info
#0  1  4  7  4  4  1  abc         4       your
#1  2  5  8  5  5  1  dfg         5     master
#2  3  6  9  6  6  1  ghj         6       data
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to learn more about other functions, its interesting there are so many functions and ways to do it.

Comment: it seems like it only work it sorted or ordered columns, what about if it is not ordered>

Comment: you only need pass `sort=False`. Check now!, thanks @Jezrael

Comment: Can I know where to pass the sort=False?

Comment: Yea, i try the above example from jezrael and it wont work now. Can guide us please.

Comment: It seems bug, so not idea for correct solution here.

Comment: Yea, but I really hope this works because its easy to understand with this method and very pandas way.

Comment: I solved it with `to_series()`. I update my solution

Comment: Great! Is it possible to share how can I arrange it back in order if can. ^^

Comment: I tried using .sort_index(axis=1) but since we have str in the .columns so it wont work. Can you teach me or show me how>

Comment: thank you for the update but the sort-index you updated above wont work.

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

Comment: I think the errors still occured, the order is ordered but the value is not in par. Everything became messy. Can you verify. thanks

Comment: I think better is use `sort_index` before change the type of columns

Answer (score 2):

General solution is try convert to integers and if not possible return same values in custom function with `rename`:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return int(float(x))
    except:
        return x
df_p = df_p.rename(columns=f)
print (df_p)
   1  2  3  4  5  6 info  new_info new_t_info
0  1  4  7  4  4  1  abc         4       your
1  2  5  8  5  5  1  dfg         5     master
2  3  6  9  6  6  1  ghj         6       data
```

Or if possible convert first 6 values to `int`s and add another values joined with lists:

```
df_p.columns = df_p.columns[:6].astype(float).astype(int).tolist() + df_p.columns[6:].tolist()
print (df_p)
   1  2  3  4  5  6 info  new_info new_t_info
0  1  4  7  4  4  1  abc         4       your
1  2  5  8  5  5  1  dfg         5     master
2  3  6  9  6  6  1  ghj         6       data
```